# NASA Asterank request returns same every time

Tags: c#, api, http, request

I am working on a project that also involves querying data from NASA's JPL Asterank API.
The problem is that I want to query asteroids depending on their names eg: Photographica, Ceres etc. 
However it doesn't return the results I am expecting.
Eg: This query returns Ceres even though I am asking for Pallas:

http://www.asterank.com/api/asterank?query={%22name%22:{%22$lt%22:"Pallas"}}

What should I do so that it actually returns me the body I want. 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://www.asterank.com/api/asterank?query= { "name" : "Pallas" } &limit=1
```

(See http://www.asterank.com/api)

I think that the `$lt` in your query made it return the asteroids "less than" Pallas, meaning "Ceres".